# How to add a selector for a form submit, only if specific button type caused the form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on("submit", "form", function () {

        $(this).find('.btn-primary').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#progress').show();
    });
    $('body').on("change", "form", function () {

        $('.btn.btn-primary').prop("disabled", false);
        $('#progress').hide();


    });
});
```

But how I can force the script to fire only if a button that have `.btn.btn-primary` caused the form to submit, while if I submit the form using for example button of class `.btn.btn-default` to not fire the above script?

**EDIT**
I tried this but now the script will never fire:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
        //^^ use document instead of body
        //check if button has btn.btn-default class and if exist return 
        if($('button').hasClass('btn.btn-default')){
            return;
        }
        $(this).find('.btn-primary').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#progress').show();
    });

$(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
        //$('form').change(function () {
        $('.btn.btn-primary').prop("disabled", false);
        $('#progress').hide();


    });
});
```

Comment: Note: Due to a bug with `body`, it is best/safest to attach delegated event handlers to `document` *as the default* (if no ancestor is closer/convenient).

Answer (score 2):

You can return the form if button has class using [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass)

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
//^^ use document instead of body
//check if button has btn.btn-default class and if exist return 
        if($('button').hasClass('btn.btn-default'){
            return;
         }
        $(this).find('.btn-primary').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#progress').show();
    });
```

Comment: but how i can make this more general so that i script will execute only if the button hasClass   = .btn-primary? as currently i will need to add all the classes i do not want to be able to fire the script   inside the if "if($('button').hasClass('btn.btn-default'){"

Comment: i wrote the following $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
        //^^ use document instead of body
        //check if button has btn.btn-default class and if exist return 
        if(!$(this).find('btn-primary')){
            return;
        }
        $(this).find('.btn-primary').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#progress').show();
    });

Comment: but currently the script will never fire

Comment: You're missing the dot in find('btn-primary') should be find('.btn-primary')

Comment: here is the full script :- $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
        //^^ use document instead of body
        //check if button has btn.btn-default class and if exist return 
        if($('button').hasClass('.btn.btn-default')){
            return;
        }
        $(this).find('.btn-primary').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#progress').show();
    });

$(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
        //$('form').change(function () {
        $('.btn.btn-primary').prop("disabled", false);
        $('#progress').hide();
   });
});

Comment: In your edit you're using the dot in hasClass() method remove the dot and should work fine...

Comment: when you use find() use the dot and when you use the hasClass() don't use the dot as it would check for the class....

Comment: ok i modify it ,, but still the script will never fire ... i mean if i click on a button with "btn btn-primary" class, the button will not be disabled and the progress will not show !!

Comment: did you try? `if(!$(this).find('.btn-primary'){`

Comment: but i think this will not work in general,, because on the same form i will have two buttons one of type .btn-default while the other of type .btn-primary

Comment: why i am confusing ,, now inside the same form i will have different types of buttons some that are within btn-default and the other are within btn-primary.. so i need to only run the script if the form is submitted by a btn-primay button

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for multiple *combined* classes, so you must separate the classes in `hasClass` with a `space` (not the dot):

```
    // if the button has both classes
    if($('button').hasClass('btn btn-default')){
        return;
    }
```

e.g. text example: http://jsfiddle.net/80001ra0/